# Swift 2: testing using Protocol-Oriented Programming instead of mock objects?

Tags: unit-testing, protocols, swift2, gamekit

The new Protocol-Oriented features in Swift 2 were introduced at WWDC with much ballyhoo, including the claim "it also saves us from having to make mocks all the time".

That sounds great--I'd love to be able to write tests without mocks.

So I set up a nice protocol/extension pair for GKMatch, like so:

```
protocol SendData {
  func send(data: NSData)
}

extension GKMatch: SendData {
  func send(data: NSData) {
    do {
      try self.sendData(data, toPlayers: self.players,
        dataMode: .Reliable)
    } catch {
      print("sendData failed with message: \(error)")
    }
  }
}

//Now what? How to test without a GKMatch or mock GKMatch?
```

Since GKMatch can't be instantiated directly, in order to do tests in the previous version of Swift I had to build a mock GKMatchmaker that would return a mock GKMatch and it was a whole complicated thing. That's why my ears perked up at that line in the WWDC talk.

But if the protocol-oriented approach is enabling freedom from mocks here, I'm not seeing it.

Can anyone show me how I'd test this code without making a mock?

Comment: sendData() is a GKMatch method, accessible because it's in an extension to GKMatch

Answer (score 3):

I think I've figured this out thanks to GoZoner's run at it. It's different enough that I think it warrants a separate answer.

First: the WWDC talk may have been referring to testing things that have been built using Protocol-Oriented concepts from the ground up. In such cases, perhaps mocks can be avoided altogether.

But: when working with classes built with the Object-Oriented approach, such as `GKMatch`, Protocol-Oriented concepts won't let you avoid mocks. However, they will make the creation of mocks *very, very easy.*

So: here's a way to make a Protocol-Oriented mock of GKMatch.

Start by defining a protocol with the GKMatch methods and properties you want to test:

```
public protocol GKMatchIsh {
  var players: [GKPlayer] {get}
  func sendData(data: NSData, toPlayers players: [GKPlayer],
  dataMode mode: GKMatchSendDataMode) throws
}
```

Then *declare that GKMatch adopts that protocol*:

```
extension GKMatch: GKMatchIsh {}
```

This is where the magic happens; where protocols make mocking very, very easy.

Once you declare that protocol adoption, you will see an error if GKMatch *does not already conform to the protocol*. In other words, you can be *absolutely certain* that your protocol *exactly* matches the methods in GKMatch, because if it doesn't, `extension GKMatch: GKMatchIsh {}` will cause an error. All you have to do is correct `GKMatchIsh` until you don't see an error, and you know you've got an air-tight definition for a proper mock.

So, using that definition, here's an example of a proper mock.

*Note: I'm entering all this in a Playground, so that I can do very simple tests. You can paste all this code into a Playground to see it run. It should be evident how to transfer the concepts to the XCTest framework, though, if you're familiar with that.*

```
public struct EZMatchMock: GKMatchIsh {
  public var players = [GKPlayer.anonymousGuestPlayerWithIdentifier("fakePlayer")]
  public init() {}
  public func sendData(data: NSData, toPlayers players: [GKPlayer],
    dataMode mode: GKMatchSendDataMode) throws {
      //This is where you put the code for a successful test result.
      //You could, for example, set a variable that you'd check afterward with
      //an XCTAssert statement.
      //Here, we're just printing out the data that's passed in, and when we run 
      //it we'll see in the Playground console if it prints properly.
      print(String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
  }
}
```

Now, to bring this back to the question of testing, here's a way you could continue to use Protocol-Oriented concepts to add behavior to `GKMatch` *and test it*. You don't need the `SendData` protocol that I was attempting at first. You can just directly extend `GKMatchIsh`:

```
extension GKMatchIsh {
  public func send(data: NSData) {
    do {
      try self.sendData(data, toPlayers: self.players, dataMode: .Reliable)
    } catch {
      print("sendData failed with message: \(error)")
    }
  }
}
```

Now again, to point out the magic here: because of `extension GKMatch: GKMatchIsh {}`, we know this will actually work with GKMatch, because if it didn't it would throw an error. And any test you do of your mock should also be a valid test of GKMatch.

Here's one way you could then test `GKMatchIsh`, then. Create a struct that takes a `GKMatchIsh` object, and uses it to call the new method that was just defined:

```
public struct WorksWithActualGKMatchToo {
  var match: GKMatchIsh
  var testData = "test succeeded".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
  public init (match: GKMatchIsh) {
    self.match = match
  }
  public func sendArbitraryData() {
    match.send(testData)
  }
}
```

And, finally, using a Playground, instantiate the struct and test it:

```
let ezMock = EZMatchMock()
let test = WorksWithActualGKMatchToo(match: ezMock)
test.sendArbitraryData()
```

If you paste all this in to a Playground, when it runs you will see "test succeeded" printed out in the debug console. And though you're only directly testing `EZMatchMock`, you are technically *also* tesing `GKMatch` *itself*.

To sum up: if I'm getting this right, this is how Protocol-Oriented concepts let you easily create very solid mocks, and then easily extend their behavior, and then easily test those extensions--knowing that the *exact same code* will be used by the real object being mocked.

Below I've collected all the code above into one chunk, so you can paste it into a Playground and see it work:

```
import Foundation
import GameKit

public protocol GKMatchIsh {
  var players: [GKPlayer] {get}
  func sendData(data: NSData, toPlayers players: [GKPlayer],
    dataMode mode: GKMatchSendDataMode) throws
}

extension GKMatch: GKMatchIsh {}

public struct EZMatchMock: GKMatchIsh {
  public var players = [GKPlayer.anonymousGuestPlayerWithIdentifier("fakePlayer")]
  public init() {}
  public func sendData(data: NSData, toPlayers players: [GKPlayer],
    dataMode mode: GKMatchSendDataMode) throws {
      //This is where you put the code for a successful test result.
      //You could, for example, set a variable that you'd check afterward with
      //an XCTAssert statement.
      //Here, we're just printing out the data that's passed in, and when we run 
      //it we'll see in the Playground console if it prints properly.
      print(String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
  }
}

extension GKMatchIsh {
  public func send(data: NSData) {
    do {
      try self.sendData(data, toPlayers: self.players, dataMode: .Reliable)
    } catch {
      print("sendData failed with message: \(error)")
    }
  }
}

public struct WorksWithActualGKMatchToo {
  var match: GKMatchIsh
  var testData = "test succeeded".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
  public init (match: GKMatchIsh) {
    self.match = match
  }
  public func sendArbitraryData() {
    match.send(testData)
  }
}

let ezMock = EZMatchMock()
let test = WorksWithActualGKMatchToo(match: ezMock)
test.sendArbitraryData()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe along these lines:

```
protocol SendData {
  func send (data: NSData)
}

protocol HasSendDataToPlayers {
  func sendData(_ data: NSData,
     toPlayers players: [GKPlayer],
         dataMode mode: GKMatchSendDataMode) throws 
}

extension SendData where Self == HasSendDataToPlayers { // 'where' might be off
  func send(data: NSData) {
    do {
      try self.sendData(data, toPlayers: self.players,
        dataMode: .Reliable)
    } catch {
      print("sendData failed with message: \(error)")
    }
  }
}

// Test Support (did I 'move the mock'?)

struct MyMatch : HasSendDataToPlayers {
  func sendData(_ data: NSData,
     toPlayers players: [GKPlayer],
         dataMode mode: GKMatchSendDataMode) throws {
    print("Got data")
  }
}

XCTAssertEquals(MyMatch().send(<data>), "Got data")
```

Comment: It might be a mock by another name, yeah. `extension SendData where Self == HasSendDataToPlayers {` will fail because it references `self.players`, which is a property of `GKMatch` but not `MyMatch` (the struct you defined). This means, to make it work, we'd have to add a `players` property to MyMatch, and every subsequent time we reference another part of GKMatch we have to add it to MyMatch. Which does end up seeming a lot like a mock.

Comment: Right, I missed the reference to `self.players` it would need to be added to `Has...`  The point though is `send()` only need be implemented once and I don't have to mock GKMatch, only `Has...`.  Similar to the way the Protocol Oriented demo code using different Renderers to test the implementation.

Comment: Which is a good step, but not the magic promised in the demo. I believe he said something about how, using mocks, it takes a lot of time to make the mocks and in the end you're just testing your mock. I don't see how this addresses those issues--you're still spending time simulating GKMatch and then testing your own implementation of that simulation. All of which said, perhaps the magic he spoke of only applies if you're building something Protocol-Oriented from the ground up. In this case, where we're starting with an Object-Oriented class, perhaps all those benefits don't appear.

Answer (score 0):

The 'magic bullet' that most solutions seem to be missing is the ability to stub an object's behavior at runtime, but easily depend on the original behavior.  I wrote a little tool called [MockFive](https://github.com/DeliciousRaspberryPi/MockFive) that I think solves this problem.  The cost is a little boilerplate, but in return you get the power of OCMock or Cedar but complete Swifty type safety.

As long as you have stubbing, you can write a single mock and then use it everywhere, no matter what your test requirements--just stub in the behavior that you need.  This has benefits in both classes and protocols: in a class, your mock subclass can call super by default, and give you vanilla object behavior unless you change it.  In a protocol, you create one mock that has reasonable default values, and you can substitute it in anywhere.

I wrote an article on how to do this with MockFive at my blog [here](http://pairtree.io/2016/01/10/mockfive-simple-reliable-mocks-in-swift/), but the gist of it is...

For a class like this

```
class SimpleDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    @objc func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }
    @objc func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 4 }
    @objc func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Production Text"
        return cell
    }
}
```

You write a mock like this

```
class SimpleDataSourceMock: SimpleDataSource, Mock {
    let mockFiveLock = lock()

    @objc override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return stub(identifier: "number of sections", arguments: tableView) { _ in
            super.numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView)
        }
    }

    @objc override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return stub(identifier: "number of rows in section", arguments: tableView, section) { _ in
            super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
        }
    }

    @objc override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return stub(identifier: "cell for row", arguments: tableView, indexPath) { _ in
            super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

And get behavior like this.

```
class ViewControllerSpecs: QuickSpec {
    override func spec() {
        let mockDataSource = SimpleDataSourceMock()
        let controller = ViewController(dataSource: mockDataSource)

        beforeEach {
            mockDataSource.resetMock()
        }

        describe("default behavior of SimpleDataSource") {
            beforeEach {
                controller.tableView.reloadData()
            }

            it("should have the correct number of rows") {
                expect(controller.tableView.visibleCells.count).to(equal(4))
            }

            it("should put the correct text on the cells") {
                expect(controller.tableView.visibleCells.first?.textLabel?.text).to(equal("Production Text"))
            }

            it("should interrogate the data source about the number of rows in the first section") {
                expect(mockDataSource.invocations).to(contain("tableView(_: tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: 0) -> Int"))
            }
        }

        describe("when I change the behavior of SimpleDataSource") {
            beforeEach {
                mockDataSource.registerStub("number of sections") { _ in 3 }

                mockDataSource.registerStub("number of rows in section") { args -> Int in
                    let section = args[1]! as! Int
                    switch section {
                    case 0: return 2
                    case 1: return 3
                    case 2: return 4
                    default: return 0
                    }
                }

                mockDataSource.registerStub("cell for row") { _ -> UITableViewCell in
                    let cell = UITableViewCell()
                    cell.textLabel?.text = "stub"
                    return cell
                }
                controller.tableView.reloadData()
                controller.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }

            it("should have the correct number of sections") {
                expect(controller.tableView.numberOfSections).to(equal(3))
            }

            it("should have the correct number of rows per section") {
                expect(controller.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)).to(equal(2))
                expect(controller.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(1)).to(equal(3))
                expect(controller.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(2)).to(equal(4))
            }

            it("should interrogate the data source about the number of rows in the first three sections") {
                expect(mockDataSource.invocations).to(contain("tableView(_: tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: 0) -> Int"))
                expect(mockDataSource.invocations).to(contain("tableView(_: tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: 1) -> Int"))
                expect(mockDataSource.invocations).to(contain("tableView(_: tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: 2) -> Int"))
            }

            it("should have the correct cells") {
                expect(controller.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0))!.textLabel!.text).to(equal("stub"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```